# springApplicationAdminRegistrar : Invocation of init method failed: nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

when trying to run my spring app which usesClassPathXmlApplicationContext  after running spring boot,
I am getting this exception:

```
2016-12-25 01:24:53.033  WARN 7992 --- [nio-8089-exec-1] figurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor : Multiple PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer beans registered [org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0, org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#1], falling back to Environment
2016-12-25 01:24:53.314  WARN 7992 --- [nio-8089-exec-1] o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/admin/SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
2016-12-25 01:24:53.314  INFO 7992 --- [nio-8089-exec-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2016-12-25 01:24:53.327 ERROR 7992 --- [nio-8089-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/admin/SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication] with root cause

javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
```

full log:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

2016-12-25 01:24:07.618  INFO 7992 --- [           main] com.airspan.testspan.smarphones.Boot     : Starting Boot on ASIL-ASHIBER with PID 7992 (C:\Users\ashiber\spring-workspace\smarphones\target\classes started by ashiber in C:\Users\ashiber\spring-workspace\smarphones)
2016-12-25 01:24:07.626  INFO 7992 --- [           main] com.airspan.testspan.smarphones.Boot     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-12-25 01:24:07.711  INFO 7992 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@776aec5c: startup date [Sun Dec 25 01:24:07 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-12-25 01:24:09.241  INFO 7992 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
2016-12-25 01:24:09.901  INFO 7992 --- [           main] a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader : Skipping bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=velocityEngine,declaringClass=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.velocity.VelocityAutoConfiguration$VelocityWebConfiguration]: a definition for bean 'velocityEngine' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.
2016-12-25 01:24:10.214  INFO 7992 --- [           main] c.s.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer : Loading properties file from class path resource [smartPhones.properties]
2016-12-25 01:24:10.971  INFO 7992 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8089 (http)
2016-12-25 01:24:10.985  INFO 7992 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-12-25 01:24:10.986  INFO 7992 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
2016-12-25 01:24:11.181  INFO 7992 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-12-25 01:24:11.181  INFO 7992 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3478 ms
2016-12-25 01:24:11.407  INFO 7992 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-12-25 01:24:11.414  INFO 7992 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-12-25 01:24:11.415  INFO 7992 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-12-25 01:24:11.415  INFO 7992 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-12-25 01:24:11.415  INFO 7992 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-12-25 01:24:12.168  INFO 7992 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@776aec5c: startup date [Sun Dec 25 01:24:07 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-12-25 01:24:12.256  INFO 7992 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/iperf/getme]}" onto public void com.airspan.testspan.smarphones.Controllers.IperfController.get()
2016-12-25 01:24:12.258  INFO 7992 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/iperf/magic],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.airspan.testspan.smarphones.Controllers.IperfController.runIperf(com.airspan.testspan.smarphones.Controllers.Wrappers.MagicIperfWrapper) throws java.lang.InterruptedException
2016-12-25 01:24:12.260  INFO 7992 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-12-25 01:24:12.261  INFO 7992 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-12-25 01:24:12.305  INFO 7992 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-12-25 01:24:12.305  INFO 7992 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-12-25 01:24:12.363  INFO 7992 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-12-25 01:24:13.042  INFO 7992 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.v.velocity.VelocityConfigurer    : ClasspathResourceLoader with name 'springMacro' added to configured VelocityEngine
2016-12-25 01:24:13.044  INFO 7992 --- [           main] o.s.ui.velocity.SpringResourceLoader     : SpringResourceLoader for Velocity: using resource loader [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@776aec5c: startup date [Sun Dec 25 01:24:07 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy] and resource loader paths [classpath:/templates/]
2016-12-25 01:24:13.106  WARN 7992 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.v.VelocityAutoConfiguration      : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Velocity configuration, or set spring.velocity.checkTemplateLocation=false)
2016-12-25 01:24:13.210  INFO 7992 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-12-25 01:24:13.305  INFO 7992 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8089 (http)
2016-12-25 01:24:13.310  INFO 7992 --- [           main] com.airspan.testspan.smarphones.Boot     : Started Boot in 6.243 seconds (JVM running for 7.154)
2016-12-25 01:24:52.134  INFO 7992 --- [nio-8089-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-12-25 01:24:52.134  INFO 7992 --- [nio-8089-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-12-25 01:24:52.158  INFO 7992 --- [nio-8089-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 24 ms
2016-12-25 01:24:52.274  INFO 7992 --- [nio-8089-exec-1] o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext   : Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1749f68c: startup date [Sun Dec 25 01:24:52 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-12-25 01:24:52.275  INFO 7992 --- [nio-8089-exec-1] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
2016-12-25 01:24:52.806  INFO 7992 --- [nio-8089-exec-1] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
2016-12-25 01:24:52.979  INFO 7992 --- [nio-8089-exec-1] c.s.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer : Loading properties file from class path resource [smartPhones.properties]
2016-12-25 01:24:52.981  INFO 7992 --- [nio-8089-exec-1] c.s.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer : Loading properties file from class path resource [smartPhones.properties]
2016-12-25 01:24:53.033  WARN 7992 --- [nio-8089-exec-1] figurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor : Multiple PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer beans registered [org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0, org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#1], falling back to Environment
2016-12-25 01:24:53.314  WARN 7992 --- [nio-8089-exec-1] o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/admin/SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
2016-12-25 01:24:53.314  INFO 7992 --- [nio-8089-exec-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2016-12-25 01:24:53.327 ERROR 7992 --- [nio-8089-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/admin/SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication] with root cause

javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.boot.admin.SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar.java:92) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.airspan.testspan.smarphones.Utils.ContextFactory.getAplicationContextInstance(ContextFactory.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.airspan.testspan.smarphones.Client.AppRunner.<init>(AppRunner.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.airspan.testspan.smarphones.Client.IperfAppRunner.<init>(IperfAppRunner.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.airspan.testspan.smarphones.Controllers.IperfController.runIperf(IperfController.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

anyone have any idea how to solve this?

jar file to a sample project:
[sample.jar link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e2q45wtl2jvipu0/sample.jar?dl=0)

Answer (score 5):

Disable "Enable JMX " in Run Configuration of Eclipse/STS

Comment: Also work for IDEA 2022.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by adding spring property file application.properties with these proprties :

```
# ADMIN (SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration)
spring.application.admin.enabled=true
spring.application.admin.jmx-name=org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication # JMX name of the application admin MBean.
```

all spring properties can be found here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: Thanks but that looks like to a workaround, not a fix. This reminds me of [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7179). Are you using Spring Boot 1.4.2? If not, please upgrade without that change.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I now upgraded to 1.4.3 but I still get the exception without those properties.

Comment: Meh. Can you share a sample that reproduces the issue please?

Comment: I could not reproduce it on another project.. on my project when getting to the line:

Comment: context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(APPLICATION_CONTEXT_XML);

Comment: I see in the logs that it is loaded twice:
Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
 Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
 [nio-8089-exec-1] c.s.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer : Loading properties file from class path resource [smartPhones.properties]
c.s.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer : Loading properties file from class path resource [smartPhones.properties]
 Multiple PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer beans registered [org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0,

Comment: OK, the good news is that it's your fault apparently ;-) Still I wonder how we could end up in such situation. If you can create a project, please open an issue in Spring Boot to see if there is anything we can do to prevent that.

Comment: Okay! I could reproduce it. 
the the is that the boot is running on the same package that the other beans get scanned.
I will edit the post with the zip file to a sample project.

the context application is loaded twice, although there is only one component scan (which is located in applicationContext.xml)

Answer (score 1):

You should disable JMS agent in run configuration
[image]